# How to shift first point in a cyclic path?

Tags: asymptote

Given a guide (or path) g that is cyclic I would like to construct an identical guide, except that all control points are shifted `n` places. The consequence is that the first and last node are shifted eg. if a, b, c and d are nodes of a cyclic path that begins with a, after a shift of `n=2` the resulting path should be c, d, a, b, beginning with c.

In my attempt I tried to extract control points and tension parameters from the guide, but it seems I cannot set those fields in the guide I construct. This is what I have tried:

```
guide rotate_seam(guide g, int n)
{
    guide res;
    tensionSpecifier T[], t;
    pair[] P;
    T.cyclic = true;
    P.cyclic = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < length(g); ++i)
    {
        t = tensionSpecifier(g, i);
        P.push(point(g, i));
        T.push(t);
    }
    T = T[n:n+T.length];
    P = P[n:n+P.length];
    for (pair i : P) { res = res..i; }
    res = res..cycle;
    for (int i = 0; i < T.length; ++i)
    {
        t = tensionSpecifier(res, i);
        t.in = T[i].in;
        t.out = T[i].out;
        t.atLeast = T[i].atLeast;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Doing this with guides will be difficult, because guides can contain different levels of specification about different segments. But if you're willing to use paths, try `return subpath(g, n, length(g) + n) & cycle`.

Comment: @CharlesStaats The code compiles, but it doesn't seem to shift the nodes at all.

Comment: It should produce results very similar to your answer. How are you determining that the nodes are not shifted?

Comment: @CharlesStaats I draw a unit circle, and a dot at its first node. Then I do the same for the result of the function and note if the two points differ. If it passes that test I further test it on an actual path I'll be using it on.

Comment: When I use my code for `rotate_seam` and then run `write(rotate_seam(unitcircle, 2))` I get something that starts at `(-1,0)`, which is definitely not the first node of `unitcircle`: `(-1,0).. controls (-1,-0.552284749830793) and (-0.552284749830793,-1)
 ..(0,-1).. controls (0.552284749830793,-1) and (1,-0.552284749830793)
 ..(1,0).. controls (1,0.552284749830793) and (0.552284749830793,1)
 ..(0,1).. controls (-0.552284749830793,1) and (-1,0.552284749830793)
 ..cycle`

Comment: @CharlesStaats I am very sorry, I just tested it again and it seems to work fine. Please make an answer so I can accept it as the obviously more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fairly short solution:

```
path rotate_seam(path g, int n) {
  // Ensure path is cyclic so that `subpath` can extend past the end of the path.
  if (!cyclic(g)) g = g & cycle;
  return subpath(g, n, length(g) + n) & cycle;
}
```

Note that `& cycle` discards the final node in the path and puts the first node in its place, which is the right thing to do if the final node was actually the same point as the first node.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The new guide is build up segment by segment by using the control point information. AFAIK there is no way of passing any sort of structure containing control points and let Asymptote build the guide to spec.

```
struct CPoint
{
    pair ctrl;
    pair pre_ctrl;
    pair post_ctrl;
}

guide rotate_seam(path p, int n)
{
    CPoint P[];
    P.cyclic = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < length(p); ++i)
    {
        CPoint tmp;
        tmp.ctrl = point(p, i);
        tmp.pre_ctrl = precontrol(p, i);
        tmp.post_ctrl = postcontrol(p, i);
        P.push(tmp);
    }
    P = P[n:n+P.length];
    guide res, seg;
    for (int i = 0; i < P.length - 1; ++i)
    {
        seg = P[i].ctrl..controls P[i].post_ctrl and P[i + 1].pre_ctrl..P[i + 1].ctrl;
        res = res & seg;
    }
    seg = P[P.length - 1].ctrl..controls P[P.length - 1].post_ctrl and P[0].pre_ctrl..P[0].ctrl;
    res = res & seg;
    return res & cycle;
}
```